Getting a bounding box for the collective elements in an SVG file
I would like to use Python to arrive at the bounding box for the figures in an SVG file.  All the previous questions I have seen on this suggest using svgpathtools; unfortunately the svg2paths() function appears to ignore transformations. The results of path.bbox() reflect only a path's original size and orientation.
So far I've been working with wand, svgpathtools, and svgutils and haven't figured out how to do it.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.
Sample SVG file.  Per Inkscape the bounding box origin would be (-31.865, -2.089) with a width of 125.506 and height of 122.263.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' standalone='yes'?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="90.708px" viewBox="0 0 90.708 94.48750000000001" height="94.48750000000001px">
  <g>
    <g transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1 1) "><g id="surface1">
            <path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0.000000,0.000000 C 3.202144,0.225136 6.404288,0.450272 11.172053,0.536923 C 15.939818,0.623574 22.273204,0.571741 27.554076,0.925336 C 32.834949,1.278931 37.063309,2.037953 35.648244,6.440268 C 34.233179,10.842583 27.174691,18.888191 31.712487,23.977375 C 36.250282,29.066559 52.384362,31.199318 56.928215,27.093757 C 61.472068,22.988196 54.425695,12.644316 55.059756,6.440268 C 55.693817,0.236220 64.008312,-1.827996 68.942070,-1.566377 C 73.875827,-1.304759 75.428847,1.282693 78.493045,1.931395 C 81.557244,2.580097 86.132622,1.290049 90.708000,0.000000 "/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0, 94.48750000000001) scale(1 1) "><g id="surface1">
            <path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0.000000,0.000000 C 4.796465,1.110848 9.592931,2.221697 13.427625,3.058108 C 17.262318,3.894519 20.135241,4.456493 24.818464,4.158698 C 29.501687,3.860902 35.995211,2.703336 35.648244,6.440268 C 35.301277,10.177200 28.113820,18.808630 32.830160,22.679254 C 37.546500,26.549878 54.166636,25.659696 58.472337,21.890080 C 62.778037,18.120464 54.769301,11.471414 55.059756,6.440268 C 55.350211,1.409122 63.939856,-2.004121 69.136278,-1.954217 C 74.332699,-1.904314 76.135896,1.608735 79.165646,2.511629 C 82.195395,3.414523 86.451698,1.707261 90.708000,0.000000 "/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g transform=" rotate(90.000000 0.000000 0.000000)"><g id="surface1">
            <path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0.000000,-0.000000 C 3.534227,-1.548330 7.068455,-3.096659 11.846284,-1.397831 C 16.624114,0.300997 22.645547,5.246982 28.082023,5.820586 C 33.518498,6.394190 38.370017,2.595412 37.133587,6.708612 C 35.897158,10.821813 28.572780,22.846993 33.799143,28.101613 C 39.025507,33.356233 56.802612,31.840294 61.374997,26.534758 C 65.947382,21.229222 57.315048,12.134089 57.353912,6.708613 C 57.392777,1.283136 66.102842,-0.472683 71.212659,-0.347371 C 76.322475,-0.222059 77.832044,1.784385 81.111143,2.155802 C 84.390242,2.527219 89.438871,1.263609 94.487500,-0.000000 "/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(90.708, 0) scale(1 1)  rotate(90.000000 0.000000 0.000000)"><g id="surface1">
            <path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0.000000,-0.000000 C 5.109947,1.642275 10.219893,3.284550 14.784916,3.298100 C 19.349938,3.311649 23.370037,1.696472 28.019442,1.345420 C 32.668846,0.994368 37.947557,1.907441 37.133587,6.708613 C 36.319618,11.509784 29.412967,20.199054 33.997583,24.341663 C 38.582199,28.484272 54.658081,28.080221 59.123581,24.053771 C 63.589080,20.027320 56.444196,12.378472 57.353913,6.708613 C 58.263629,1.038753 67.227946,-2.652116 72.059494,-2.421833 C 76.891041,-2.191549 77.589819,1.959887 80.639025,3.017051 C 83.688231,4.074215 89.087866,2.037108 94.487500,-0.000000 "/>
        </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


After posting this I realized I can parse the output of "inkscape --query-all", so at least I have a backup plan.

wrap everything in an untransformed group  and get the bounding box for the g

I'm not clear what you mean.  What you are describing appears to be the exact structure of the attached example SVG file that's failing with svgpathtools.
